# Is it possible to make the generic varargs methos compile without changing the method body?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

Consider this generic swap method:

```
package chapter06;

public class Ex05VarargsSwap {


public static <T> T[] swap (int i, int j, T... values) {


    T temp = values[i];
    values[i] = values[j];
    values[j] = temp;
    return values;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double[] result = Ex05VarargsSwap.swap(0,1, 1.5,2,3);

    /* The Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from 
    * Number&Comparable<?>&Constable&ConstantDesc[] to Double[]
    */

    Double[] result2 = Ex05VarargsSwap.<Double>swap(0,1,1.5,2,3);
    /* The parameterized method <Double>swap(int, int, Double...) of type Ex05VarargsSwap is not 
    * applicable for the arguments (int, int, Double, Integer, Integer)
    */      

}

}
```

Is there a way to make this code compile without changing the method?

Of course the call: `Double[] result3 =  Ex05VarargsSwap.swap(0, 1, 1.5, 2.0, 3.0);` compiles.

But I want the call to be compiled without changing the argument's type. (maybe with annotations, or casting... etc.)

Comment: Hi, @user85421 I just wanted to be sure that there is nothing else that can be done before I change the arguments.

Comment: What is the problem with changing the arguments? why can't you do it? if you don't pass all doubles, then you are not calling the method, you are calling a method that doesn't exist

Comment: Why should it return Double[]?  You didn't pass it a series of doubles (you have a mixed set of int and double).  You can have different types in the varargs list but only if they have a common type - in this case the ints and doubles become Integer and Double which have the common type Number.  Hence the return type is Number[] when you invoke it with a mixed list.

Answer (score 1):

`T...` means `array of T`, same as `T[]`. You can't have 2 types in it. In your example you try to put ints and doubles, you can't have `T` be both int and double at the same time

You need to give a list of doubles so `2` and `3` won't do, you need to use `2d` and `3d` or `2.0` and `3.0`

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] result = Ex05VarargsSwap.<Double>swap(0, 1, 1.5, 2d, 3d);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have the comfort of a static method, without a need to create a new object.

Comment: @HodiyaEyal I edited my answer, you can keep the static method

Comment: yes `3d` or `3.0`, both should work, they are both doubles. But `3` doesn't work, it is an int

Comment: but question already had that and explicitly asking for "without changing the argument's type"

Comment: @HodiyaEyal Well, `T...` means `array of T`, same as `T[]`. You can't have 2 types in it. In your example you try to put ints and doubles, you can't have T be both int and double at the same time.

Comment: "You can't have 2 types in it." Well, you *can* in this case, because the `T` is used as the parameter types, so you can use a supertype, and any 2 types will always have a common supertype, which in the worst case can be `Object`. However, the problem in this case is the array of the common supertype (which according to the error message is something like `Number&Comparable<?>&Constable&ConstantDesc[]`) is not assignable to `Double[]`.